# Постоянное автоматическое обновление значения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт

```
var heightW = $(window).height(); 
var widthW = $(window).width();
document.write(heightW);
```

Он выводит высоту окна на страницу (пример http://beilec.ru.tf/)
Мне нужно, чтобы это значение постоянно обновлялось без перезагрузки страницы, проверялось не изменилось ли оно
Каким образом это можно реализовать?
Искал на сайтах, ничего дельного не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

нужно повесить ваш js код определения размера на событие onResize. т.к. в пользуетесь jQuery то событие называется resize